# Arrow in tikzpicture between two nodes with midway label

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to draw a series of labelled nodes in Tikzpicture, so far I have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style = {draw, semithick, minimum size=1cm}]
  \node at (0, 3*3) [box] (0) {Node};
  \node at (0, 3*2) [box] (1) {Node};
  \node at (0, 3*1) [box] (2) {Node};
  \node at (0, 3*0) [box] (3) {Node};
  \draw (0) -> (1) node [midway, fill=white] {Label 1};
  \draw (1) -> (2) node [midway, fill=white] {Label 2};
  \draw (2) -> (3) node [midway, fill=white] {Label 3};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But unfortunately I cannot figure out, despite looking on S.O and on search engines, how to get a arrow, rather than the straight line. What format should I use to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Where did you get this code from? Replace `\draw (0) -> (1)` by `\draw[->] (0) -- (1)` or `\draw[<->] (0) -- (1)`.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment. - Could you specify your problem or does @marmots comment solves your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I put three different arrow heads in the code. You are to tell Ti*k*Z how it is supposed to draw arrows and other stuff in square brackets after `\draw`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style = {draw, semithick, minimum size=1cm}]
  \node at (0, 3*3) [box] (0) {Node};
  \node at (0, 3*2) [box] (1) {Node};
  \node at (0, 3*1) [box] (2) {Node};
  \node at (0, 3*0) [box] (3) {Node};
  \draw[->] (0) -- (1) node [midway, fill=white] {Label 1};
  \draw[-latex] (1) -- (2) node [midway, fill=white] {Label 2};
  \draw[-stealth] (2) -- (3) node [midway, fill=white] {Label 3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

as supplement [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) to answer, alternative code for nodes placement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style = {draw, semithick, minimum size=1cm}]
  \node at (0, 3*3) [box] (0) {Node};
  \node at (0, 3*2) [box] (1) {Node};
  \node at (0, 3*1) [box] (2) {Node};
  \node at (0, 3*0) [box] (3) {Node};
  \draw[->]         (0) -- node [fill=white] {Label 1} (1) ;
  \draw[-latex]     (1) -- node [fill=white] {Label 2} (2) ;
  \draw[-stealth]   (2) -- node [fill=white] {Label 3} (3) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the result is the same.